# Remove glitch/flicker on window(scroll) jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This function is adding a desired class when the certain element is reached, but elements seems to shake constantly after that. Is there something wrong with this way of applying class on scroll? Here's a demo(please reduce window size if needed so you can scroll past the content): https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ooZZja

```
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var os = $(".header").offset().top;
    var ht = $(".header").height();
    if (scroll > os + ht) {
      $(".header").addClass("is-fixed");
    } else {
      $(".header").removeClass("is-fixed");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: becuase your fixed class probably removes content and the height changes.

Comment: Is there any known workaround for this?

Comment: pad the top of the body to be same size as header you remove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are calculating the offset of the header while scrolling. Because you set the position to fixed it will change and the calculations aren't valid anymore. You need to save the initial position of your header element before attaching the scroll event to the window object.

I also added a "ghost element", so your content height won't change after you made the header element fixed. The ghost element will occupy the space if the fixed element was detached from its position.

Forked pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GOWWwo

HTML:

```
<tr class="header">
  <th>1</th>
  <th id="day-in-week-0">Mon</th>
  <th id="day-in-week-1">Tue</th>
  <th id="day-in-week-2">Wed</th>
  <th id="day-in-week-3">Thu</th>
  <th id="day-in-week-4">Fri</th>
  <th id="day-in-week-5">Sat</th>
  <th id="day-in-week-6">Sun</th>
</tr>
<tr class="ghost"></tr>
```

CSS:

```
.header:not(.is-fixed) + .ghost {
  display: none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){      
  var os = $(".header").offset().top;
  var ht = $(".header").height();

  $('.header + .ghost').css({
    height: ht + 'px'
  });

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll > os + ht){
      $('.header').addClass('is-fixed');
    } else {
      $('.header').removeClass('is-fixed');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it just with css, with `position: sticky;`

```
.is-fixed {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

And apply this class to table

```
<table class='is-fixed'>
```

Working example : [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WXppKj)

---

**Issue with current code is :**

> becuase your fixed class probably removes content and the height
>   changes
>
> as @epascarello told you in comment

Answer (score 0):

Changing the table row to fixed is affecting the measurements and it constantly toggles between the two states.
I would copy the row and show it when needed.

```
<p><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eligendi explicabo dolore odit facilis debitis ducimus repudiandae vero? Dolore ab id suscipit repudiandae quidem, atque recusandae! Impedit blanditiis tempora illum optio?</div></p>
<p><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eligendi explicabo dolore odit facilis debitis ducimus repudiandae vero? Dolore ab id suscipit repudiandae quidem, atque recusandae! Impedit blanditiis tempora illum optio?</div></p>
<p><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eligendi explicabo dolore odit facilis debitis ducimus repudiandae vero? Dolore ab id suscipit repudiandae quidem, atque recusandae! Impedit blanditiis tempora illum optio?</div></p>
<p><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eligendi explicabo dolore odit facilis debitis ducimus repudiandae vero? Dolore ab id suscipit repudiandae quidem, atque recusandae! Impedit blanditiis tempora illum optio?</div></p>
<p><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eligendi explicabo dolore odit facilis debitis ducimus repudiandae vero? Dolore ab id suscipit repudiandae quidem, atque recusandae! Impedit blanditiis tempora illum optio?</div></p>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="header">
            <th>1</th>
            <th id="day-in-week-0">Mon</th>
            <th id="day-in-week-1">Tue</th>
            <th id="day-in-week-2">Wed</th>
            <th id="day-in-week-3">Thu</th>
            <th id="day-in-week-4">Fri</th>
            <th id="day-in-week-5">Sat</th>
            <th id="day-in-week-6">Sun</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="is-fixed" style="display:none;">
            <th>1</th>
            <th id="day-in-week-0">Mon</th>
            <th id="day-in-week-1">Tue</th>
            <th id="day-in-week-2">Wed</th>
            <th id="day-in-week-3">Thu</th>
            <th id="day-in-week-4">Fri</th>
            <th id="day-in-week-5">Sat</th>
            <th id="day-in-week-6">Sun</th>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>

<p><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eligendi explicabo dolore odit facilis debitis ducimus repudiandae vero? Dolore ab id suscipit repudiandae quidem, atque recusandae! Impedit blanditiis tempora illum optio?</div></p>
<p><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eligendi explicabo dolore odit facilis debitis ducimus repudiandae vero? Dolore ab id suscipit repudiandae quidem, atque recusandae! Impedit blanditiis tempora illum optio?</div></p>
<p><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eligendi explicabo dolore odit facilis debitis ducimus repudiandae vero? Dolore ab id suscipit repudiandae quidem, atque recusandae! Impedit blanditiis tempora illum optio?</div></p>
<p><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eligendi explicabo dolore odit facilis debitis ducimus repudiandae vero? Dolore ab id suscipit repudiandae quidem, atque recusandae! Impedit blanditiis tempora illum optio?</div></p>
<p><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eligendi explicabo dolore odit facilis debitis ducimus repudiandae vero? Dolore ab id suscipit repudiandae quidem, atque recusandae! Impedit blanditiis tempora illum optio?</div></p>
<p><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eligendi explicabo dolore odit facilis debitis ducimus repudiandae vero? Dolore ab id suscipit repudiandae quidem, atque recusandae! Impedit blanditiis tempora illum optio?</div></p>
<p><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eligendi explicabo dolore odit facilis debitis ducimus repudiandae vero? Dolore ab id suscipit repudiandae quidem, atque recusandae! Impedit blanditiis tempora illum optio?</div></p>
<p><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eligendi explicabo dolore odit facilis debitis ducimus repudiandae vero? Dolore ab id suscipit repudiandae quidem, atque recusandae! Impedit blanditiis tempora illum optio?</div></p>
```

Css

```
.is-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  display:table-row;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        var os = $(".header").offset().top;
        var ht = $(".header").height();

        if(scroll > os + ht){
            $('.is-fixed').show()
        } else {
            $('.is-fixed').hide();
        }
    });
});
```